# run app on physical device in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm running app on my phone but after some time passes then it gives me error on bundle..
warn No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.

Comment: Can you give some more information? What operating system are you using? What phone with what OS are you connecting?

Comment: is it an Android or ios device?

Comment: @christianost, it was showing an error that "No device connected" when my physical device connected via USB is disconnected.

Comment: @Alirezatk was using android and windows os.

Comment: @monikmane Have you can through the steps described here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#running-your-app-on-android-devices?
I would also check that `adb devices` gives you a list of devices, at least one should appear.
When connecting your Android phone, you can sometimes select a mode (like photo sharing etc.). I would set this to ”Only charging” and see if it helps.